# I am trying to change a variable value in one click but when I am reverting the change using if else loop it is taking me 2 clicks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

```
function ProductItem(props) {
   var addedToCart = false
   const valuesCart = {
       val1 : "Add to cart",
       val2 : "Added to cart"
   }
   const [changedText , setText] = useState(props.type)
   const [changedBtnText , setBtnText] = useState(valuesCart.val1)
   
   const clickHandler = () => {
       console.log(addedToCart)
       if(!addedToCart){
           setText(valuesCart.val2)
           setBtnText(valuesCart.val2)
       }
       else{
           setText(props.type)
           setBtnText(valuesCart.val1)
       }             
       addedToCart = !addedToCart
       console.log(addedToCart)  
   }
```

> Here I am Initializing addedToCart variable to check whether item is already added to cart

```
var addedToCart = false
```

> The clickHandler function is triggered by onClick event.

```
const clickHandler = () => {
```

> This is used for debugging puposes

```
       console.log(addedToCart)
```

> This checks if the addedToCart variable is false and sets the values of item type and button label to "Added To Cart"

```
       if(!addedToCart){
           setText(valuesCart.val2)
           setBtnText(valuesCart.val2)
       }
```

> The else loop should trigger when the addedToCart variable is True and then it will set the item type and button label back to there initial values before the first click.

```
       else{
           setText(props.type)
           setBtnText(valuesCart.val1)
       }             
       addedToCart = !addedToCart
```

> This is used for debugging purposes

```
       console.log(addedToCart)  
   }
```

> This is what the output on console looks like when I am clicking the Add To Cart button for 3 times

[After the First click The outputs are (false, true) which is as expected but after the second click the output should be (true, false) whereas it is coming the same (false, true) and after the 3rd click the output is the required output i.e. (truem false)][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/12pH1.png

> > The false and true indicate the value of addedToCart variable.

> Help me solve this issue and get the button to behave as a toggle switch which can alter is value with a single click.

Comment: Why dont you want to convert `var addedToCart = false` to `var [addedToCart, setAddedToCart] = useState(false);`? addedToCart is just resetting to false on component rerender.

Answer (score 0):

I think this line addedToCart = !addedToCart should occur before the if statement. Try it and see.

Comment: Yes I tried it ...but it is is just shifting the extra click to the start instead of after the first click i.e. first click does nothing if addedToCart !=addedToCart is moved before if statement.
Thanks for the response!!

Comment: Or maybe move it inside the if. Like 
        if(!addedToCart){
           setText(valuesCart.val2)
           setBtnText(valuesCart.val2); addedToCart = true
       }
       else{
           setText(props.type)
           setBtnText(valuesCart.val1); addedToCart = false
       }

Comment: Okk will try that and let you know....